# Time/Score relation in flappy bird

Tags: flappy-bird

Well it's a really simple question but I wonder how long i have to play for a certain score ;).

As far as I know the distance between the pipes always stay the same, so what is exact amount of time between those pipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it and the time is about ~1,5 sec. From start to first pipe ~4 sec. (It's not as easy to check clock and play the same time)
When i would have someone who stop the time it would be more accurate.